# Ajax delete quest not entering the REST endpoint

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest

I've been trying to create a delete endpoint so i can perform the operation. However it does my ajax does not enter the rest endpoint and skips to the error clause of the call!

Here's how my ajax call looks like:

```
$('#datatable_col_reorder').on('click', '#tableDeleteButton', function() {
        var selectedId = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:first').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'delete',
            url: '/delete/profile/' + selectedId,
            success: function(){
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

And here is my java rest endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/profile/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
private ResponseEntity<?> deleteProfile(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    System.out.println("id");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

I have tried various request - passing the id in the url or as a data field, i tried different anotations in the delete method.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The docs say this about the error callback:
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

So you can see the exact error by alerting/logging the passed params. The callback would then look like this:

```
error: function(xhr, status, err){
           console.log(xhr, status, err);
        }
```

Isn't the problem in the annotation?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/profile/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

The `method = RequestMethod.GET` should be `method = RequestMethod.DELETE`?

Comment: Ah i forgot it to "GET" when i was testing. because with get it worked but no when i do DELETE then i get the error!
i executed your suggestion and i get - {"timestamp":"2019-07-21T14:36:25.596+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/delete/profile/1"}"

Comment: 403 Forbidden says it all. You don't have access to the /delete/profile/1. Backend problem. Or maybe some authentication headers missing?

Comment: I dont know about the headers. Im new to the ajax calls. How can i check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274610/403-response-for-post-put-delete-request-in-spring-boot-spring-security-applic might help