# Keep getting 403 forbidden from spring boot example code

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, authentication

I followed a simple tutorial for newbie for spring boot and setup my first controller and a few API calls. However, I was able to call GET but the POST always gives me 403 error code from postman and curl.

Here is my relevant code

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Here is my controller code

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Create a new order")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/orders", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Order createOrder(
            @ApiParam(value = "New order object", required = true)
            @RequestBody Order newOrder) {
        newOrder.setSymbol(newOrder.getSymbol().toUpperCase());
        return orderRepository.save(newOrder);
    }
```

Here is the http response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-08T19:57:03.487+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/v1/orders"
}
```

I'm requesting with curl as such

```
curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/orders --data "test"
```

**I know its not a CORS issue, I've tried several other auth methods and all of them gives 403 (not 401)**

Comment: You haven't included your request itself. (Also note that your `produces` is unnecessary and you can just use `@PostMapping("/orders")`.)

Comment: I added my curl request. Also tried postmapping, same thing

Comment: Assuming that your curl request is a typo (quoting), you didn't provide any authentication--that's basically what 401/403 is for.

Comment: can you add OPTION also in allowed http method ` configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("OPTION")) and check

Answer (score 2):

You can try to look at CSRF parameter.

[HttpSecurity POST 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037161/httpsecurity-post-403-forbidden)

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
  }
```

Comment: You should not disable CSRF if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give permission to all for that url:

```
   http
      .csrf().disable()
       and().
         authorizeRequests().
         antMatchers("/api/v1/orders").permitAll();
```

I don't know if you really need to disable CORS. If you don't, remove the `cors.disable()` line

Comment: `.and()` can't come after `.csrf().disable()`